# Printing first line of text file

Tags: java

I am using the scanner method for my '**MyZoo**' class to read tab separated text files like this:

```
import shipment of April 12, 2007
# tab separated data
Bird    Golden Eagle    Eddie
Mammal  Tiger   Tommy
Mammal  Lion    Leo
Mammal  Elephant    Eddie
Bird    Parrot  Polly
# last one next
Reptile Cobra   Colin
```

I have split up the three colums of data: **`Type, Species and name`**.

However the **first line of data is NOT animal data**, so I use "scanner.nextLine" before the while loop to ignore it, HOWEVER **I would still like it to be printed to the terminal**, just not being read as Animal Data.

Code:

```
   scanner.nextLine();
   while(scanner.hasNextLine())
   {
   String type = scanner.next();
   String species = scanner.next();
   String name = scanner.next();
   System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());
   System.out.println(type + "  " + species + " " + name);
   scanner.nextLine();

   addAnimal( new Animal(species, name, this) );

   String line = scanner.nextLine();
   if(line.startsWith("#"))
    {
       continue;
    }
    else
    {
        scanner.nextLine();
        addAnimal( new Animal(species, name, this) );
    }
}
```

Comment: Just do what you already do in the loop then  : `System.out.println(scanner.nextLine())` .

Answer (score 3):

Just change your initial `nextLine` call to print it out:

```
   System.out.println(scanner.nextLine()); // Change here
   while(scanner.hasNextLine())
   {
   String type = scanner.next();
   String species = scanner.next();
   String name = scanner.next();
   System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());
   System.out.println(type + "  " + species + " " + name);
   scanner.nextLine();

   addAnimal( new Animal(species, name, this) );

   String line = scanner.nextLine();
   if(line.startsWith("#"))
    {
       continue;
    }
    else
    {
        scanner.nextLine();
        addAnimal( new Animal(species, name, this) );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, i was a little sceptical of this working at first, but i guess its the way to do it. :)